# Custom frame as a link?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I am trying to make a custom frame that turns the whole content element into a single button using the destination set in the Header link field.

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
  100 = TEXT
  100.value = <a id="c{field:uid}" class="myclass" href="{field:header_link}">|</a>
  100.insertData = 1
}
```

It doesn't work because the header is still linked making a link within a link. Is there a way to disable the link on the header so I can link the whole thing instead?

Comment: The href is only here, in your example not closed, or is it a typo which kills your a tag in your real code as well?

Comment: @AndrásOttó Unfortunately that was just a typo in my question, not in the real code.

Comment: @AndrásOttó I've realized the problem is because it is creating a link within a link. Do you know how I could disable the link on the header so the outer link will work?

Comment: On the same way, you should change the rendering of the header through the tt_content.